# Xcode 12 loses tabs after restarting

Tags: ios, xcode

After upgrading to Xcode 12, I noticed that it would drop tabs. Apple has a new tab system with Window and Document (new) tabs. In the past I would create a different tab for different functions - one to look at graphics (storyboards and xibs), another for debugging, another for git, etc.  I would have like 5 different tabs.  I have found that if I exit a project, but then bring it back the tabs are there.  But if I exit Xcode and then go back to the project, that only 2 tabs come back.  I also played with Navigation Style - Open in Place under Preferences/Navigation.  Hoping to get the old style back - but still am losing tabs.

Any thoughts on what is going on. Or tips to save one’s setup. Or how best to get along with the new system.

Answer (score 0):

This problem went away with Xcode update: Version 12.0.1 (12A7300)

Comment: For me it still happens in Version 12.2 (12B45b)

Comment: Yea, the problem is still there.

Comment: Yes, the problem does keep recurring.